# R: Create dataframe from paste0 content

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I am manually creating a "free text" table using `cat` and `paste0` like so:

```
tab < - cat(paste0("Stage","\t","Number,"\n",
                   "A","\t",nrow(df[df$stage == "A",]),"\n",
                   "B","\t",nrow(df[df$stage == "B",]),"\n"
            ))
```

i.e.

```
Stage    Number
A        54
B        85
```

where I want to be able to create a publication ready table (i.e. looks good and probably generated by r markdown.

The `xtable()` function can do this, but only accepts a dataframe. So my question is how to I get some free text, delimited by column using "\t" and by rows "\n" into a dataframe?

I have tried:

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(as.character(tab),'\t')))
```

But get "dataframe with zero columns and zero rows". I think this has to do with the fact I am not declaring "\" to be a new line.

By the way, if this way seems long-winded and there is an easier way, I am happy to take suggestions.

Comment: Try `read.table(text="")` to re-import your string as a data.frame. Or even better, create it as a data.frame in the first place rather than a string.

Comment: @excellent this worked thanks.